# How to install Tsintermittent package in google colab?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory, cran, intermittent

[image: Error code]

I'm new to R programming and not able to install the tsintermittent package in google colab using R.

https://rdrr.io/cran/tsintermittent/

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to install the `tsintermittent` package as follows.

Create a new Python Colab notebook with this in the first code cell.

```
import rpy2
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

And this in the second.

```
%%R
install.packages("tsintermittent")
```

This installation takes a long time but once it's done, this piece of code works.

```
%%R
library(tsintermittent)
?crost

#File: /tmp/Rtmpavwtu6/Rtxt3e47d2a422
#crost              package:tsintermittent              R Documentation


#Croston's method and variants 
#...
```

Comment: I'm getting error while installing tsintermittent in Jupyter notebook. Error in library(tsintermittent): there is no package called ‘tsintermittent’
Traceback:

1. library(tsintermittent)

Comment: It works for me. The second cell that installs the package took 8 minutes for me just now, how long did it take when you ran it?